# How to handle multiple environments with Google Cloud Build and Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, devops, google-kubernetes-engine

I'successfully set up a CICD pipeline following [this tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/gitops-cloud-build).

It shows clearly how to make Google Cloud Build and Kubernetes work with one environment: production.

> For simplicity, this tutorial uses a single environment —production—
>   in the env repository, but you can extend it to deploy to multiple
>   environments if needed.

Right, but some details are missing: is there one kubernetes.yaml file by environment? What about kubernetes namespaces?...

More precisely, what would be the way to handle multiple environments (staging...)?

Answer (score 0):

There could be a bizillion ways of doing environments , but what I understand from this line:

**env repository: contains the manifests for the Kubernetes Deployment**

That the default master/production branch maps to the production environment , then you can create for example testing , and staging branches , where you test and stage your things , and later on port the change to master branch.

Infact if you keep reading that document , it will tell you something:

> The env repository can have several branches that each map to a
>   specific environment (you only use production in this tutorial) and
>   reference a specific container image, whereas the app repository does
>   not.

One more thing , if you have access to gitlab and kubernetes , you can implement it without google GKE and clud build.

Comment: About the master branch, I suppose you're referring to the app repo because the env repo have the 'production' branch instead. What about the k8s manifest in the app repo then ? Would you create different files : kubernetes-production.yaml, kuberntes-staging.yaml ... or would have a unique kubernetes.yaml whose content would be different from on branch to the other ?

Comment: No I mean the production branch , whatever u call it. so you need to create a branch for each envionment in env repo

Comment: yes , one deployment file who environement varibles , labels and image tag would be different for each envionment

Comment: In that case, imagine I'd like to limit the CPU for a container only in the staging env for example. That update in the staging branch would be merged and deploy in master/production when I merge staging (with some features) to master. Any way to avoid it ?

Comment: yes , in that case, use deployment variables , either in helm chart fashion or use terraform, or simple used sed inside the pipeline to replace the values of place holders in kube yaml. in short , keep the deployment manifest parameterized

Comment: I see. I'd like to go with sed for simplicity. However, there are some configs more difficult to parameterize. How can I make an ingress rule be activated in one env and not on the other ?
Moreover, where would the different values (provided to sed) be stored ? Directly in cloudbuild.yaml with a switch-like structure (for handling the multiple envs) ?
Another way would be to create in the app repo, two config files : kubernetes-common.yaml and kubernetes-staging.yaml. Any cons about this way ?

Comment: what about running two branches in parallel , independent of each other

Comment: The author recentlly added a note mentioning Kustomize and Skaffold. Those tools look like the right ones.

Comment: @Neko try if they work for you. othervise I would recommend using spinnaker or terraform